# How can I change Flat rate Shipping Method 'Method Name' for emails only

Tags: magento-1.9

How can I change the Flat rate Shipping Method 'Method Name' for emails & also hide 'Title' for emails only?

For e.g. Currenlty,

**Title** - Fixed

**Method Name** - Flat rate shipping

In emails it is displaying **Fixed - Flat rate shipping**

I need to display in emails only **Flatrate**

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer, it might help someone else.

I achieved it by creating custom variable in Order mail & it's function in Mage_Sales_Model_Order